# Verificação de string dentro de uma função em C

Tags: c, string, funções, comparação

Saudações!
Estou criando um programa em C onde o usuário pode alterar o estado de algum sensor digitando o nome do sensor e 1 ou 0 para mudar o estado do mesmo, sendo 1 para ligado e 0 para desligado. Porém, quando tento fazer essa condição de verificação fora da main, em uma função, não está dando certo, acredito que seja algum erro na passagem de parâmetros, se puderem me ajudar, vou colocar o código abaixo.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
char y[2];
int sensor;
int s1;
char s[2];

void verificar(char y[2], int sensor);

void main ()
{
printf("Digite o sensor que deseja alterar o estado\n");
gets(s);
printf("Ligar ou desligar? (1 ou 0)\n");
scanf("%d", &s1);
void verificar(s, s1);
}

 void verificar(char y[2], int sensor)
{
if(strcmp(y,"s1")==0 && (s1 == 1))
{
    printf("S1 ligado");
}
}
```

Quando tento rodar o programa, a verificação não ocorre.

Comment: chamar a função é apenas com o nome: `verificar(s, s1);` sem o `void`

Answer (score 1):

Cara, seu problema é que está passando errado o vetor por parâmetro. O correto ao receber um vetor por parâmetro é receber o endereço dele, ou seja, precisa de um ponteiro.

O segundo ponto é que pra chamar uma função você não coloca o void.

Com essas mudanças seu código funcionou:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

char y[2];
int sensor;
int s1;
char s[2];

void verificar(char *y, int status){
    if(strcmp(y,"s1") == 0 && (status == 1)) {
        printf("S1 ligado");
    }
}

void main () {
    printf("Digite o sensor que deseja alterar o estado\n");
    gets(s);
    printf("Ligar ou desligar? (1 ou 0)\n");
    scanf("%d", &s1);
    verificar(s, s1);
}
```

Comment: Pode haver comportamentos inconsistentes quando não é especificado o retorno da função `main`, [veja mais](http://c0x.coding-guidelines.com/5.1.2.2.1.html). O correto é implementar ela desta forma `int main(void) { /* ... */ }` e você pode retorna um valor diferente de 0 no caso do programa falhar.